# Syntax error at input 'indiseBox' in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator("heikinashi", overlay = true)

bullish_color = input(title = "Bullish Bar color", defval = color.rgb(0, 191, 255, 0))
bearish_color = input(title = "Bearish Bar color", defval = color.rgb(242, 227, 12, 0))

//เรียกค่า
heikinashi_open = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
heikinashi_high = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
heikinashi_low = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
heikinashi_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

isInside = heikinashi_high < heikinashi_high[1] and heikinashi_low > heikinashi_low[1]

var box indiseBox = na

if isInside 
     indiseBox := box.new(left = bar_index-1, top=heikinashi_high[1], right=bar_index
      bottom =  heikinashi_low[1], bgcolor = color.new(color.silver,85) , border_color = color.new(color.silver,85))
else
     box.set_right(indiseBox, bar_index)

plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title = "heikinashi", color = heikinashi_open < heikinashi_close ? bullish_color : bearish_color)
```

I don't know how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your if block must be indented by a tab or 4 spaces. The line starts with `indiseBox :=` should be indented by this rule.

The following line must be indented by one order several extra spaces (different from multiples of 4) because it is a continuation of the first line ([line wrapping](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html)).

```
if isInside
    indiseBox := box.new(left = bar_index-1, top=heikinashi_high[1], right=bar_index,
     bottom =  heikinashi_low[1], bgcolor = color.new(color.silver,85) , border_color = color.new(color.silver,85))
else
    box.set_right(indiseBox, bar_index)
```